# how to import data from gmail to a spreadsheet using script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i was wondering if i can get the new emails data and put it in a spreadsheet .. the reason i'm making this is i need to track response time with custom search criteria like "FROM:(example@ie.com OR example@ie.com OR example@ie.com) ("done" OR "file") has:attachment".
and if the search have a new email i need to return it to a new row in the sheet within functions for the required ranges.

Here is a link that describe what i need to do
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oRrB8JSR1lVHGhjBd5-BU9XxkuaBZPG_MwVq5uEiioE/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GmailApp.search('Your_serach_criteria')`. This will return an array of Gmail Threads which then you can iterate for messages and extract the required information and put in spreadsheet.

Comment: glad you answered my question, however, i'm not good enough with google API to make the script, can you please write an example for the function here.
also, i don't wanna to array all the emails that fit the criteria i need the new ones only, like an automated way to collect each mail information.

Appreciated